# "no available channels" with ubuntu dual boot on Nexus 5

Tags: dual-boot, ubuntu-touch, android

I successfully installed ubuntu touch on my Nexus 4 yesterday alongside cyanogenmod 10.2. Today I used the [method described on the ubuntu wiki](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/DualBootInstallation) to install the "Ubuntu Dual Boot Installer" on my Nexus 5 alongside cyanogenmod 11, but the app doesn't have the "Trusty" channel available like it did yesterday. It just says "Install Ubuntu--no channels available".

[This forum post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=48884484) recommend changing my /system/build.prop file to have these values:

- ro.product.model=Nexus 4
- ro.product.device=mako
- ro.product.manufacturer=LGE

But I'm afraid of what that will do to my android installation.

Comment: Working now as shown in this post, dual boot now works http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=53003439&postcount=425

Answer (score 3):

I am waiting too for a port of UbuntuTouch to Nexus 5.

Now I own a Galaxy Nexus and do not want to buy a "nexus 4" because the
16GB is to small for a phone-storage with NO SD-support.

After the UT-port to Nexus 5 I will buy one.

but unfortunately on xda-developers.com user ValoXis (who wanted to port UT to Nexus 5) wrote:
"We have found the problem. Ubuntu Touch is based on CM 10.1/2. It need to rewrite all the driver. Hwcomposer is the problem with the base. So, the project is closed. Canonical has announced that Ubuntu Touch official for N5 will be released from end of Jan/start of Feb."

see:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=49168595&postcount=34

regards 
sUbuPack

Comment: new official infos :2. Ubuntu Engineering (UE) will _continue to focus on the Nexus 4
phone platform_ and will _not adopt the new Nexus 5 platform_ short
term (before 14.04 is out). SEE:https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/msg05889.html

Answer (score 3):

Well... Im a proud owner of the Nexus 5 and currently using the catalysm rom along with multiboot. While surfing google i found an italian site that have successfully ported ubuntu touch to the nexus 5.

The rom Is around 460 mb and is lightning fast.

U might not understand italian same as me.. Just google translate.

Link:  http://www.chimerarevo.com/video/ubuntu-touch-su-nexus-5-nostra-anteprima/

Enjoy

Answer (score 2):

@kelorek:

Actually, you can. NO need to change the device info to Nexus 4.
Here is what you follow. Picking up straight from xda-developers forum.

And here it is (the dual boot)
- go to "http://humpolec.ubuntu.com/latest/" and download "dualboot.sh"

- open terminal and browse to the file you just downloaded and type "chmod +x dualboot.sh"
- then type "./dualboot.sh" (installation can stop at the moment waiting for you to reboot to bootloader but it will copmlete succsesfuly)
- boot to android and type in terminal "adb shell"
- now type `su sh 'cd /data/data/com.canonical.ubuntu.installer/files/ && echo http://system-image.tasemnice.eu > custom_server && chmod 777 custom_server'`

**Note:** When you do the last step, keep your screen on, as adb shell will ask super su to grant permission. If you don't do that in 15 mins, it will silently deny access.

Now open dual boot app in android and install ubuntu from selected channel.

**Requirements:**
- Nexus 5
- ADB tools on pc
- Unlocked bootloader
- Usb debbuging enabled

Answer (score 1):

The nexus 5 is simply not supported (yet). See [the devices list](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices).

Answer (score 0):

No support for Nexus 5 yet.

It would be very helpful to have a timeline for at least the most common Android developer devices. Support for Nexus devices is critical to get Apps published. I have published an Ubuntu Web App (desktop + touch) but was not able to test on real device. The app has a resolution-dependent issue but I cannot test on my Nexus5. This results in poor overall app quality or developers postponing their development until first Ubuntu phone is available. I will focus one the other platforms in the meantime.